# grabbing and storing multiple regex variables as an array

Tags: python, arrays, regex

I ran into problems when trying to get this code to work and am currently stuck.

At the moment I am grabbing multiple values from one pattern. The problem is that I think it stores the multiple values as a string. Ideally I want to be able to have each of the desired values stored in an array. Say there are 5 values per item and n items, I want my array to be 5 x n size. Currently it is just size n. My code is as follows:

```
import re
import pickle

regex = '''<item>
<first>(.+?)</first>
<second>(.+?)</first>
...
<fifth>(.+?)</fifth>
</item>
'''

pattern = re.compile(regex)
with open('d.dat') as searchfile:
    filetext = searchfile.read()
results = re.findall(pattern, filetext)

pickle.dump(results, open('save.p', 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
object=list(re.findall(pattern,filetext)[0])
```

`re.findall` return a *list of tuples*.So you can convert it into list again.

Comment: @Coolguy did this help you?